# A well guarded riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a game where there is only one winning move
> My infix comes after a certain family, excluding the unlucky
> My suffix is mostly for animals, and sometimes dragons
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> **warden**, a person that guards something

Line 1:

> **war**, where the only winning move is not to play. A terrifyingly relevant quote from the movie Wargames

Line 2:

> **rd**, those two letters come after every number ending with 3, with the exception of all numbers that finish with 13, which are the so-called "unlucky"

Line 3:

> **den**, either as an animal's home or TV's Dragon's Den

Comment: That is indeed correct!

Comment: @Auribouros Thanks for the puzzle! Is the infix just the rd or is it longer?

Comment: rot13(Vg vf gur eq bayl vaqrrq)

Comment: Oh that answer for 2 is fiendish. Well done!